# adding new LiteralControl to an aspx page, from aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, literals

So basicly im adding elements to my html, via litterals from the backend.
It works great when using it in the asp content placeholders. But i need it to be another specific place on a specific page. Ive tryed making div's with runat="server" But it does not seem to work.. Does anyone have any experience with what i could use? This is part of my code:

```
foreach (var something in somethingelse)
{
    this.Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceholder1")
        .Controls.Add(
         new LiteralControl("It's a long list, so just typing this.")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use runat="server" on divs. For example:

```
<div id="myNewDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

and in the code behind:

```
myNewDiv.InnerHtml = "Some new text in the div";
```

If you need to create the divs dynamically you can do the following:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var ele = new HtmlGenericControl("div")
            {
                InnerHtml = string.Format("new div {0}", i), 
                ID = string.Format("NewDiv_{0}", i)
            };

            Page.Form.FindControl("MainContent").Controls.Add(ele);
        }
```

You can even push the new divs into an existing div which is anywhere in the ContentPlaceHolder:

```
        var page = Page.Form.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("myNewDiv").Controls;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var ele = new HtmlGenericControl("div")
            {
                InnerHtml = string.Format("new div {0}", i), 
                ID = string.Format("NewDiv_{0}", i)
            };

            page.Add(ele);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a HTML tag in source as below

```
<table>
<tbody>
<-- Your literal control here -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

and in code behind set `literal1.Text ="<tr><td>'"+ Your data here +"'</td></tr>"` and it will work

Comment: It's in a foreach loop tho, so if i do that, it wont make a new literal for each item, as im litteraly naming the literal "literal" if i do that, and that will cause an issue?